# What is the process of making a black lightsaber/Darksaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* and *Star Wars: Rebels*, we see a Black lightsaber much like a real sword or katana and it was supposedly stolen from the Jedi hundreds of years prior to the Clone Wars by the Mandalorians. But what I don't know is how did it turn black because we all know a red lightsaber turns red by the process of making a kyber crystal bleed known only unto the Sith. So what makes a lightsaber black? And how did it get its Katana like shape, unlike the cylindrical round shape of normal lightsabers?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darksaber

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7HGafpav4U - Warning *Rebels* spoilers.

Comment: This is called the Darksaber.

Comment: Since it was a rebel lightsaber, wouldn't it just have been made and had that color, although being very rare, because rebels do not choose their color of lightsaber.

Comment: Step 1, call marketing budget. Step 2, profit

Answer (score 1):

I think that the darksaber isn't made from a kyber crystal. It is reasonable to assume since it is a Mandalorian weapon, that it doesn't require a force wielder to use it effectively. This is pointed out when Darth Maul fought Tor Visla (leader of the Death Watch who had the darksaber) for the leadership of the Death Watch and the blade. This was after the days of the Old Republic, when the darksaber was used to combat the Jedi. Maul with the blade also makes appearances in the Star Wars Rebels TV series. As far as for how it's made, only the Jedi Archives could tell us...